# Rspec configuration - disable request spec behaviour

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have an 'spec/acceptance' folder with the specs that should load the full stack.

I want to use the 'spec/integration' folder for specs that test interaction between models, but I don't want to load the full stack in those tests.

But rspec automatically runs tests in this folder as 'request' specs, loading the full stack. How can I disable this for this particular folder?

Comment: You'd better not fight against conventions, especially if other developers could work on your app

Comment: I don't know a better name for these kind of tests